# Adsense instead of the images

Tags: image, adsense

I have a business directory. Each user can create their own little photo gallery 
If the user does not upload a picture, I want to shows Adsense instead of the images.
Is it possible? 
Here's the code that displays the images:

```
    if ($this->config->getTemParam('skipFirstImage','0') == 1) {
    array_shift($this->images);
    }

    echo '<div class="row-fluid">';

    if (!empty($this->images)) {
    echo '<div class="span5">';
    include $this->loadTemplate( 'sub_images.tpl.php' );
    echo '</div>';
    }

    echo '<div class="span'.(!empty($this->images)? '7':' 12').'">';
    echo '<div class="listing-desc">';
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (!empty($this->images)) {
    echo '<div class="span5">';
    include $this->loadTemplate( 'sub_images.tpl.php' );
    echo '</div>';
} else {
    // adsense code goes here (echo it)
}
```

Beware that AdSense ads have their specific dimensions, maybe you'll need to include the inside a div with an appropriate class to avoid layout to mess up.